# How many emails i can send through google aps scrip?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I wanted to know how many emails I can send through google apps script using the G suite account.

Comment: Take a look at script editor help

Answer (score 0):

You can send 1500 emails per day. Please take a look at the quotas.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: But I can't send more than 100 emails/day  with G suite account

Comment: 100 emails are for the Gmail consumer account. You might be logged in two accounts in your browser and you have authorized script using your Gmail account instead of Gsuite account. If I am wrong, then you need to contact Gsute support and get help.

Comment: I already have a word with the g suite support team. they told me support for apps script is out of our scope

Comment: Hello @Developer, please bear in mind this: `Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users.`, from [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Can you confirm that this is the situation in your case? When did you upgrade to the G Suite account? Cheers!